Lengths of modules under normalization morphism
Let $X$ be a (non necessarily reduced) scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$ with char$(k) =0$ such that every quasi-compact open has finitely many irreducible components and let $\nu\colon \tilde{X} \to X$ be the normalization morphism. Let $p$ be a generic point of an irreducible component of $X$. Suppose that the pre-image of $p$ consists of $n$ points, say $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. Suppose that we know that the length of the Artin local ling $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ has length $k$ with $n|k$.
Question 1: Is there a known formula for the length of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ in terms of lengths of $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X},p_i}$ for $p_i$ in the preimage of $p$? i.e. something like
$$
\ell(\mathcal{O}_{X,p})=\sum_{i=1}^n\ell(\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X},p_i})
$$
Furthermore, if so, is there any condition on $X$ such that the length of $p$ is "equidistributed" in its preimages?. By equidistributed I mean that $\ell(\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X},p_i})=\ell(\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X},p_j})$ for any $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.
